# Is there a relationship between the $\Omega$-conjecture and choiceless large cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

Woodin’s $\Omega$-conjecture is absolute under set-forcing. One proposal to decide it is that some large cardinal hypothesis might refute it. On the other hand, Woodin is seeking extensions of the inner model program that would show the conjecture consistent with all large cardinals. However, the latter scenario doesn’t seem to speak to the possibility of a choiceless large cardinal proving the conjecture can consistently fail. What are the known possibilities here?

Comment: I'm hazy on the relationship between the $\Omega$-conjecture and the Ultimate-L conjecture, but at least according to the abstract of Bagaria, Koellner, and Woodin's [Large Cardinals Beyond Choice](https://doi.org/10.1017/bsl.2019.28), the latter is inconsistent with things like Reinhardt and Berkeley cardinals.

Comment: @TimCampion It's actually unknown whether one can refute a Reinhardt cardinal assuming the Ultimate L conjecture. Assuming the HOD conjecture (which holds if the Ultimate L conjecture can be proved), the existence of two Reinhardt cardinals can be refuted in ZF, and hence so can the existence of a Berkeley cardinal.

Comment: Are you asking about the scenario in which the Ultimate L conjecture is true? And are you interested in the $\Omega$ conjecture only in the context of ZFC?

Comment: @TimCampion Unfortunately, if there is one Reinhardt cardinal, then there are two of them, so when I said "two Reinhardt cardinals" I really meant "two elementary embeddings of the universe whose critical sequences do not have the same supremum."

Comment: @Gabe: What about two embeddings with disjoint sequences but the same supremum?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Start with an elementary embedding $j_0 : V\to V$, let $j_1 = j_0(j_0)$, and notice that $i_0 = j_0\circ j_0$ and $i_1 = j_1\circ j_1$ have disjoint critical sequences; namely, if $(\kappa_n)_{n < \omega}$ is the critical sequence of $j_0$, then $(\kappa_{2n})_{n<\omega}$ is the critical sequence of $i_0$ and $(\kappa_{2n+1})_{n < \omega}$ is the critical sequence of $i_1$.

Comment: @Gabe: Okay, but what if we also require the embeddings are "algebraically independent"?

Comment: @GabeGoldberg I'm asking about the logical connections with the $\Omega$-conjecture. In "Suitable Extender Models I," Woodin says it is a good test question to guide the development of inner models, so I want to know if choiceless LCs could have any influence.

Comment: @MonroeEskew My question (well, one of them) is whether you're interested in choiceless cardinals implying that ZFC + the negation of the $\Omega$ conjecture is consistent (since you say "consistently fail") or whether you are asking whether choiceless cardinals might refute the $\Omega$ conjecture outright, but in the context of ZF.

Comment: @MonroeEskew I'm not sure how well $\Omega$-logic fares in the choiceless context. Since stationary tower forcing seems to be off the table, it is not even clear that $\Omega$-satisfiability is absolute for set forcing assuming ZF + a proper class of Woodin cardinals. So the conjecture may need to be reformulated in this context.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Perhaps choiceless LCs imply the existence of an inner model of ZFC in which the $\Omega$ conjecture fails?